# WAMP Server error caused by .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I was using the following `htaccess` codes for `url` `rewrite` and it was working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# do not do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


# forward /john to user/profile.php?name=john
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ user/profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

However, when I upgraded to the latest `WAMP2` server, I started getting the error message below.

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Please can someone explain why I got this error, and how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: What does your error logs say? (it may say something about `RewriteEngine` being a bad directive), are you sure you have [mod_rewrite turned on](http://blog.cmstutorials.org/tutorials/tips-tricks/how-to-make-mod_rewrite-work-on-wamp)?

Comment: @JonLin Yes mod_rewrite is turned on. Let me check the error log

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite was actually turned off on the server configuration file, I turned it on, restarted the server, and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem but then i discovered that in `httpd.conf` the mod_rewrite has been Hashed out which means it is turned off so i removed the # in the beginning of the line and restarted all services and it worked out!